# Add total for all records in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to sum all records AS Total,

Before

| cards | No. Of Cards |
| --- | --- |
| First card | 100 |
| Second card | 200 |

After

| cards | No. Of Cards |
| --- | --- |
| First card | 100 |
| Second card | 200 |
| Total | 300 |

Answer (score 3):

If you used SQL*Plus's reporting capabilities, you'd `break` and `compute`:

```
SQL> break on report
SQL> compute sum of no_of_cards on report
SQL> with test (cards, no_of_cards) as
  2    (select 'first card' , 100 from dual union all
  3     select 'second card', 200 from dual
  4    )
  5  select cards, no_of_cards
  6  from test;

CARDS       NO_OF_CARDS
----------- -----------
first card          100
second card         200
            -----------
sum                 300

SQL>
```

---

Otherwise, `rollup` might do the job:

```
SQL> with test (cards, no_of_cards) as
  2    (select 'first card' , 100 from dual union all
  3     select 'second card', 200 from dual
  4    )
  5  select cards, sum(no_of_cards) no_of_cards
  6  from test
  7  group by rollup(cards);

CARDS       NO_OF_CARDS
----------- -----------
first card          100
second card         200
                    300

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte(cards,number_of_cards) as 
(
  select 'first card',100 from dual union all
  select 'second card',200 from dual
)
select c.cards,sum(c.number_of_cards)number_of_cards
from cte c
group by rollup(c.cards)
```

or you can use rollup

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT cards, no_of_cards
FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(no_of_cards)
FROM table_name;
```

---

[**Here is a full demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9cMautw)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using [`CUBE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-aggregation-data-warehouses.html#GUID-C5FDD050-DCE0-4FE1-9741-420E2F970A36) such as

```
SELECT NVL(cards,'Total') AS "cards", SUM(no_of_cards) AS "No. Of Cards"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY CUBE(cards)
 ORDER BY cards NULLS LAST
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VFOxBgfM)</kbd>